# chart.js gradient background problems with browser zoom

Tags: javascript, background, gradient

I have a gradient in my chart.js as background.
This works well if my screen zoom is set to 100%

If I change my zoom ([Strg] + [+] or [-]), the gradient doesn't take this in account.
What can I do?

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
const labels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
  }]
};

const plugin_gradient = {
  beforeDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
    const ctx = chart.ctx;
    const canvas = chart.canvas;
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
    var gradientBack = canvas.getContext("2d").createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height, canvas.width, 0);
    gradientBack.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 120, 120, 1)");
    gradientBack.addColorStop(.5, "rgba(255, 255, 120, 1)");
    gradientBack.addColorStop(0, "rgba(120, 255, 120, 1)");
    ctx.fillStyle = gradientBack;
    ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.top - chartArea.bottom);
  }
};

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  plugins: [plugin_gradient],
  options: {}
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mickna/ur7ja4wg/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this guy on youtube: [Chart JS](https://www.youtube.com/c/ChartJS-tutorials) with "[How to Create Diagonal Gradient Background in ChartArea in Chart JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6JqlI-0CMY)" my gradient is now working for me.

The working plugin part:

```
const plugin_gradient = {
        id : "plugin_gradient",
        beforeDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
            const { ctx, chartArea: { top, bottom, left, right, width, height } } = chart;
            ctx.save();
            
            const gradientColor = ctx.createLinearGradient(left, bottom, right, top);
            gradientColor.addColorStop(0, "rgba(120, 255, 120, 1)");
            gradientColor.addColorStop(.5, "rgba(255, 255, 120, 1)");
            gradientColor.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 120, 120, 1)");
            
            ctx.fillStyle = gradientColor;
            ctx.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
            ctx.restore ();
          }
      };
```

A JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mickna/4ytezxdn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to play with the canvas.width and height parameter, eg:

`window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth`

Comment: Thank you 01p. I found a working solution :)